# sum of 2 different queries result

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join

I have to do **sum from 2 different tables** and show it using **MySQL**:

total comments from table 1, total comments from table 2: What i have tried so far is,

```
SELECT u.name as name, u.username as username, 
( SELECT SUM(total) FROM (SELECT (COUNT(nc.id)) as total FROM table1 as nc WHERE nc.user_id = u.id) UNION ALL (SELECT COUNT(pc.id) AS total FROM table2 pc WHERE pc.user_id = u.id) as finalTotal ) as total_comments
FROM user as u 
GROUP BY u.id
```

It is giving me this **error**:

> Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Look at error message. That was the answer.

Comment: @RubahMalam but all table have alias

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you need, you have to modify the query like this :

```
select u.name,u.username,total as total_comments
from user as u
left join (
    select id,sum(total) as total 
    from(
        select nc.id,count(1) as total
        from table1 as nc
        group by nc.id
        union all
        select pc.id,count(1) as total
        from table2 as pc
        group by pc.id
    ) as t group by id
) comments on comments.id = u.id
```

Comment: it is giving *NULL* in **total as total_comments**

Answer (score 0):

Before UNION ALL put alias like you giving for all..

```
SELECT u.name as name, u.username as username, 
( SELECT SUM(total) FROM (SELECT (COUNT(nc.id)) as total FROM table1 as nc WHERE nc.user_id = u.id) as vr UNION ALL (SELECT COUNT(pc.id) AS total FROM table2 pc WHERE pc.user_id = u.id) as finalTotal ) as total_comments
FROM user as u 
GROUP BY u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.name as name, u.username as username, 
( SELECT SUM(total) FROM 
  (SELECT (COUNT(nc.id)) as total FROM table1 as nc WHERE nc.user_id = u.id

  UNION ALL SELECT COUNT(pc.id) AS total FROM table2 pc WHERE pc.user_id = u.id) as finalTotal ) as total_comments
FROM user as u 
GROUP BY u.id
```

Remove brackets before and after `UNION ALL` and check.